# Get data from website based on parameters

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I need to get the dividend yield for the following site https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/dividends_declared/index.php?sel_year=2021 through excel or power bi.

I need to get data based on the year filter i.e., if my data requires for multiple years, it should get the dividend yield for a company for those periods selected.

Is it possible to do this in excel or in power bi?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways to do this.

### I. Using Power Query (from Excel or Power BI).

Under Data Tab - From Web - then input your URL
i.e. https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/dividends_declared/index.php?sel_year=2019

You can see there is query parameter at the end of this URL.

i.e. If you want to switch to 2020, you just change 2019 to 2020.
https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/dividends_declared/index.php?sel_year=2020.

You could establish multiple queries, then you could append those queries based on the years you want in a later stage.

### II. Use Power BI's "Run Python script feature"

Use Python in Power BI - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts#:~:text=To%20enable%20Python%20scripting%3A%201%20In%20Power%20BI,local%20path%20is%20C%3A%5CPython.%20...%203%20Select%20OK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20Python%20scripting%3A%201%20In%20Power%20BI,local%20path%20is%20C%3A%5CPython.%20...%203%20Select%20OK).

Once you know how to use Python in Power BI queries steps, simply write a script, something like this.

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = []
for year in [2018, 2019]:
    # get data from url
    data = pd.read_html(f'https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/marketinfo/dividends_declared/index.php?sel_year={year}') 
    
    # transfer the raw data to a dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1])
    new_header = df.iloc[1]
    df = df[2:]
    df.columns = new_header
    
    # add df into the container list
    dfs.append(df)
# concate all dfs into one
com_df = pd.concat(dfs)
com_df
```

Output

```
COMPANY NAME    Type    %   Announcement    Record  Ex-Dividend
2   Coal India  Interim 72.50   17-12-2018  31-12-2018  28-12-2018
3   RITES   Interim 47.50   17-12-2018  28-12-2018  27-12-2018
4   IOC Interim 67.50   13-12-2018  25-12-2018  21-12-2018
5   Dharamsi Morarj Interim 5.00    07-12-2018  21-12-2018  20-12-2018
6   Aarey Drugs Interim 1.00    30-11-2018  14-12-2018  13-12-2018
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1695    Bajaj Consumer  Interim 1400.00 09-01-2019  21-01-2019  18-01-2019
1696    TCS Interim 400.00  31-12-2018  18-01-2019  17-01-2019
1697    Vishal Bearing  Interim 5.00    03-01-2019  15-01-2019  14-01-2019
1698    Shanthi Gears   Interim 500.00  26-12-2018  07-01-2019  04-01-2019
1699    Selan Explore   Interim 50.00   24-12-2018  05-01-2019  03-01-2019
```

### III. You also could use some Python libraries that deeply
integrated with Excel, something like pyxll or xlwings.

These tools allow you have better interactions with native excel operations by using UDFs. For example, you could create a function i.e "get_dividend_by_year(year)", it takes year or years as params that you can link with the Excel cells.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with the first option? I was able to get for one year but is it possible for me to create the url based on a cell and then get the data from online automatically using macro or by any other means?